# Run a crontab for django management command with an argument

Tags: python, django, cron

I wish to ping_google for the sitemap every 10 minutes using crontab and django manage.py

I need to run the following on server-
`python manage.py ping_google /sitemap.xml`

I am not sure how to give the parameter '/sitemap.xml' in the crontab. Here is what I have

`*/10 * * * * /home/project/.virtualenvs/app/bin/python /home/project/workspace/app-backend/django-app/manage.py ping_google /sitemap.xml`

Am I passing the argument correctly? How am I supposed to pass the argument?

Comment: What is the backslash doing here?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I fixed the mistake. Here, `/sitemap.xml` represents the address of the sitemap on the website

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be better here to write a small shell script here that sets the current working directory correctly, and activates the virtual environment. For example a file `command.sh` in the directory `/home/project/workspace/app-backend/django-app/`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# cd to the correct directory
cd "/home/project/workspace/app-backend/django-app/"

# source the virtual environment
. /home/project/.virtualenvs/app/bin/activate

# call the command
python manage.py ping_google /sitemap.xml
```

Then you can run this with:

```
*/10 * * * * bash /home/project/workspace/app-backend/django-app/command.sh
```